# How to have a bibliography style like Google Scholar?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, typography, google-scholar

My goal is to achieve this Google Scholar style:

[image]

- Entries are ordered as type->title->author->year->publisher->URL
- Types are all caps (better: small caps), and in square brackets before titles
- Titles of any type are large and in boldface
- Only authors, years, publishers and URL are in the second line

## Problems

- How to show the type entry (book, article, artwork, unpublished)
- How to swap entries?
- How to make the author entry not showing `family=X, given=Y`?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [book,article,artwork,unpublished,website]
  {title}{{\textbf{#1}}\newline}
  
\DeclareNameFormat
  [book,article,artwork,unpublished,website]
  {author}{{\small{#1}}}
  
\renewbibmacro*{title+author}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>FYI: [How to make bibliography tailored for non-academic readers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/102834/26474)</sup>

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/50146 is also about how the field contents are displayed, not only which fields. You would need to give more details about your desired style. (How are `@incollection`s displayed, how `@article`s?) But at the moment your question comes down to: Please code the entire style for me. It is not unheard of that questions like these are answered on this site. But they are not particularly well suited to the Q&A format where ideally you would focus on one particular issue.

Comment: Oh  my god. Is there really a style like this? It looks imho rather horrible.

Comment: Well at least there is now only one fontfamily. But you still have two weights, two font sizes and two shapes. You are not writing a titlepage of the 19th century but  some bibliography entries,  there is no need to shout. I would use neither bold, nor a larger font, only perhaps some italic for the title.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as I read the question there actually is a need to shout, that seems to be the point of the desired new style.

Comment: @Marijn I don't see why a bib entry should shout. People who look at it are already interested enough.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer when I first did my undergraduate dissertation, I didn't understand why the titles didn't stand out. I still don't understand it. For me it's a natural thing to think of. The titles are interesting, the authors are not (unfortunately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define a new bibliography driver and make all entry types use the same driver.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace\bibrangedash\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{entrytype}{{\small{\textsc{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{googlescholarlike}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{entrytype}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \printunit{\newline}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{eprint}
       {\printfield{url}}
       {\usebibmacro{eprint}}}
    {\printfield{doi}}% 
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.5\baselineskip}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\makeatletter
\def\do#1{\DeclareBibliographyAlias{#1}{googlescholarlike}}
\abx@doentrytypes
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,ctan,cicero,worman,nussbaum,baez/online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Can the numbers be removed?

Comment: @Ooker Have a look at the edited answer, please. Of course there is no good way to cite the items any more.

Comment: What do you mean in the last sentence? I don't understand it

Comment: @Ooker I mean to say that it is not clear at all what citations (in the text) should look like now. You haven't specified that and in the MWE `\cite` will produce numbers, but those are obviously useless now.

Comment: No, I don't use inline citation. This is written for popular audience, so I omit all distractions in the text

Comment: the titles aren't emboldened if the package ebook is used. Is there any other option to make it bold besides using `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}`? Trying `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\textbf{#1}}` doesn't help

Comment: @Ooker Works for me in the MWE if I change `\documentclass{article}` to `book` and load `\usepackage{ebook}`. Please test if this really has something to do with `biblatex`. Does `\textbf{foo}` work at all? You might want to ask a new question about that.#

Comment: are you using pdfLaTeX? I use XeLaTeX. It seems that it's the limitation of the package on the bibliography

Comment: @Ooker Indeed, if compiled with XeLaTeX you'll find `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'TU/cmss/bx/n' undefined using 'TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 61.` in the log. This means that the font does not have a bold shape if used with XeLaTeX. This is not a problem of the bibliography, but a general thing. `\textbf{foo}` doesn't work either. The package if used with XeLaTeX completely disables all font commands.

Comment: That's weird. I get similar warnings like that, but using `\textbf{foo}\textit{foo}` is fine. Document classes are book or report

Comment: @Ooker Please make an MWE and ask a new question. Make it as minimal as possible. Try to reproduce the issue without `biblatex`. Since `biblatex`'s commands are only wrappers around the standard commands it would really surprise me if `\textbf` worked but `\mkbibbold` didn't. Make your MWE as short as possible and provide the `.log` file as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. [Why doesn't \mkbibbold work while \textbf does when using the ebook package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407644/50146)

Comment: Can the word `url` be removed?

Comment: @Ooker `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`