# Why doesn't \mkbibbold work while \textbf does when using the ebook package?

Tags: biblatex, bold, ebook

To activate the ebook package, one has to put `\usepackage{ebook}` in the preamble, and `\ebook` in the document. If both are activated, `\mkbibbold` stops working while `\textbf` works fine. Why is that?

I use XeLaTeX -> Biber-> XeLaTeX.

## WME

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{ebook}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Qu.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace\bibrangedash\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
%\ebook
\textbf{Bold text} \textit{Italic text}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,keyword=Projective geometry,title=Hình học xạ ảnh]
\end{document}
```

## Results

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Log file](https://pastebin.com/CfFPdBdy)

If `\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\textnormal}` is used, then the heading is not large anymore
[image]

<sup>FYI: [How to have a bibliography style like Google Scholar?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406893/50146)</sup>

Comment: Don't use the package with xelatex (actually don't use it at all, it seems to have only a vage idea about how to change the font setup and uses a more or less random set of commands).

Comment: unfortunately only XeLaTeX can produce pretty result

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't use xelatex but don't use the package `ebook` -- it is not good.

Comment: [Why is the ebook package not good to use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407902/50146)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `ebook` does not change fonts in a good way.  In particular, the result is a different set of fonts is being used in the bibliography.  To work around this you can either compile with `pdflatex` or use

```
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\textnormal}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{ebook}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Qu.bib}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addspace\bibrangedash\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\textnormal}

\begin{document}
\ebook
\textbf{Bold text} \textit{Italic text}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `Qu.bib`

```
@Book{Douglas:Moebius,
  author =   {Douglas, Arnold},
  title =    {Moebius transform},
  year =     2000
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use hyperref to avoid the border wrapping the links. The ebook package has option clash with it, even though it is only loaded once. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Use `\hypesetup` to adjust options to hyperref.

Comment: `\hypersetup{colorlinks = false,linkbordercolor = {0 0 0}}` doesn't work, while `linkbordercolor={white}` is not support. I also notice that after using `\renewcommand` the heading is not large anymore. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `\hypsetup{hidelinks=true}`.  The heading does not change size for me, but the bib text is larger; can use e.g. `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\small}` to get that text smaller again.