# Why is the ebook package not good to use?

Tags: packages, typography, ebook

As said in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406037/50146), the [ebook](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ebook?lang=en) package is convenient in making a document specialized for phone screens (font, position, spacing, etc) and it's easy to turn on or off (need not take care on the geometry and documentclass). I do see that it makes me some inconveniences, ([`\mkbibbold` doesn't work while `\textbf` does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407644/50146), only using xelatex gives the most aesthetic result), but @UlrikeFischer said that

> don't use it at all, it seems to have only a vage idea about how to change the font setup and uses a more or less random set of commands

So what are this package's disadvantages? Why is it not good to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your own previous question is already a good example for the side effects.

The package doesn't set `\normalfont` and `\normalsize` correctly. And so all commands or environments which call this commands to ensure that the main font and size of a document is correctly used will fail:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{ebook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\ebook blblblb \normalfont blblblb \normalsize blblblb 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Beside this simply loading the package will change the main font as you can try out with this document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{ebook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

bookman

\end{document}
```

### with ebook

[image]

### without ebook

[image]

Comment: but does it because it is inevitable to avoid this, or is it just a fault of the authors? Can it be improved so that the typography it sets (font, position, spacing) is still achieved while allowing for more flexibility?

Comment: it is badly coded and one could improve it.

Comment: do you know how to improve it? Telling me the direction is enough